# is there anyway to get the actual vector embedding of a word or set of characters using flair nlp? i.e flair embeddings

Tags: nlp, flair

Basically I'm trying to use a custom flair language model to get a word or sentence's embedding in a vector. Is this possible or do flair embeddings only function when using flair NER models?

When using the embeddings .embed() function I receive an output like "[Sentence: "pain"   [− Tokens: 1]]"
where as I'm looking for the vector of continuous numbers.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm quite confused because there is an [official tutorial on word embeddings by the flair authors themselves](https://github.com/flairNLP/flair/blob/master/resources/docs/TUTORIAL_3_WORD_EMBEDDING.md#classic-word-embeddings), which seems to cover exactly this topic. I guess the problem is that you are confusing the processed sentence object from `.embed()` with the actual `.embedding` property of said object.

In any case, you can simply iterate over the word embeddings of individual tokens like so (taken from the tutorial mentioned above):

```py
from flair.embeddings import WordEmbeddings
from flair.data import Sentence

# init embedding
glove_embedding = WordEmbeddings('glove')

# create sentence.
sentence = Sentence('The grass is green .')

# embed a sentence using glove.
glove_embedding.embed(sentence)

# now check out the embedded tokens.
for token in sentence:
    print(token)
    print(token.embedding)
```

I am not familiar enough with flair to know whether you can apply it to arbitrary character sequences, but it worked for tokens for me.

Comment: Thanks so much. This is actually crazy because i read over the tutorials so many times. I must've just missed it. Its been a long day.

Answer (score 0):

```
from flair.embeddings import TransformerDocumentEmbeddings
from flair.data import Sentence

# init embedding by loading the model of your choice
embedding = TransformerDocumentEmbeddings("dbmdz/bert-base-german-uncased")

# create a sentence
sentence = Sentence('Der Rasen wächst schnell')

# embed words in sentence
embedding.embed(sentence)
#get the vector
print(sentence.embedding)
```